# How can I make an number sorter using iteration Structure with this?

Tags: python

```py
def sortMyNumber(collection,asc):

xx = [0,0,0,0,0]
print("type 5 numbers")
for x in sortMyNumber(xx,True):
    print(x)
```

Comment: What is your code intended to accomplish?

Comment: there are several sorting algorithms out there! please be specific.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about sorting a list of numbers there are lots of ways to do this and you don't need a special function.  Python has what you need already.

To sort in ascending order:

- `[1, 3, 2, 5, 4].sort()`
- `sorted([1, 3, 2, 5, 4])`

Or descending order:

- `[1, 3, 2, 5, 4].sort(reverse=True)`
- `sorted([1, 3, 2, 5, 4], reverse=True)`

A benefit to the `sort()` method is that it sorts the list in place.  A benefit to sorted is it supports any iterable, not just lists.

Because the question is not clear, you might have also meant how to sort in reverse order (not strictly ascending or descending).  In that case, you could do something like this:

- `list(reversed([1, 3, 2, 5, 4]))`